# Closest not working on dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use .closest() with my HTML page. I have this HTML :

```
<body>
  <div class="listcontainer">
    //Content
    <div class="button">Ok</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When the user clicks '.button' , im adding this HTML to the above HTML dynamically through an ajax call. The ajax call, on success, appends the below html to body:

```
<div class="listpanel">
    //Content
</div>
```

So, I have listpanel below listcontainer and both of them are inside body. Now i am using .closest as:

```
$listpanel = $('.listpanel'); 
$div = $listpanel.closest('.listcontainer');
```

But somehow, the closest is selectin the html element rather than the listcontainer. I am not sure why this is happening. could someone help me with this?
Thank you.

Edit: This is how my Ajax call looks like:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
            url:"listpanel.html",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success:function(data)
            {
                    $('body').append(data);
            }
     });
});
```

Comment: So your click function does appends to `.listcontainer`?

Comment: Not very clear. Please provide your code after ajax call

Comment: @void No, my click function will append to body

Comment: Please advise on what you want to do and on what event you want to search for?

Comment: @MaxZoom I would like to find the closest .listcontainer to .listpanel and adjust the height of the .listcontainer

Comment: @Abhilash Could you please add desired output of your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attache div.listpanel to the body it is not inside the div .listcontainer. Thus the closest wont find it. You need to search for siblings:

```
var myDiv = $('.listpanel').siblings('.listcontainer').first();
```

or append it to the div .listcontainer and then use the closest() method

Comment: Thank you ! This worked. But if this worked, shouldn't ".prev('.listcontainer');" have worked too? I am confused !!! But thank you so much for your help !!

Comment: @Abhilash `.prev()` only targets the immediate preceding element. `.prevAll('.listcontainer')` would fetch you the desired result...

Comment: This call should work: $('.listpanel').prev('.listcontainer')

Answer (score 0):

`.closest` traverses the ancestor DOM tree.  It does not look at siblings or drill into siblings' sub-trees.  This is expected functionality.

http://api.jquery.com/?s=closest

Comment: but, if i consider '.listcontainer' as a sibling and use .prev(), the <script> tag is being selected (I have script tag in  the html file containing '.listpanel'). So, what would be a good way of achieving my functionality?

Comment: @Abhilash `$('.listpanel').prevAll('.listcontainer:first')`. Use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) with a selector to get all previous elements that match your selector. Optionally, I added `:first` to get only the first match...